# IOS 7 Safari stop when touch input text area for pop up keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

my service has a problem.

When user get web page through mobile safari that has a lot of html and js codes, and touch input text to type a text, keyboard popup doesn't show up and safari app stops.

Is this performance issue(because of a lot of html and js codes)? or iOS safari bugs?

When I do using Chrome or though desktop, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem on iOS 7 (while everything was okay on iOS 6): in my case, the keyboard took long (about 10 seconds) to show up and Safari was frozen during that time.

I solved the problem by upgrading to newer versions of jquery and jquerymobile, in my case from jquery 1.8.3 to 1.10.2 and from jquerymobile 1.2.0 to 1.3.2

That is to say, this solution might work for you if you use jquery and jquerymobile.